# Why can't i transfer ownership of google drive folder and files to other? (OwnershipTransfer libary is being used)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

[image: This the error I get when I run the function]

The library I am using is from [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/OwnershipTransfer).
The response has very little info to debug or I don't understand what is this. It supposed to be easy from what I read in the description.

Any help?

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my sample script is not useful for your situation. From your error message, can you provide the value of `console.log(JSON.stringify(res))`? Because in your error message, the detail error cannot be seen.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code not an image of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an intended behavior. From your screenshot, I'm assuming you're using a G Suite/Workspace account for your 5times.co.in email. Please take note that transferring files from one Workspace account to another workspace account or Gmail is not possible as of the moment.

This is a documented here: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308960

> You can transfer ownership of your Google Drive files and folders to someone else in your organization.

an alternative is to either use Shared Drive or download the file and re-upload it to your Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is:
step-1: Transfer files from the drive (your Gdrive) to google cloud storage
step-2: Transfer files from google cloud storage to drive (new Gdrive, different organization)

Reference python code for file transfer between DRIVE & Google drive.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Xc8E8mKC4MBvQ6Sw6akd_X5Z1cmHSNca

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).